# Grammar and role of the word "protected"

Tags: complements, object-complements

What is the role of the word **"protected"** in the following sentence?

> She kept her money protected in a safe.

I mean, she is the sub., kept is the v. and ... so what about the word **"protected"**?

Answer (score 1):

The word *protected* is an adjective used as an object complement or predicative complement. It is the past participle of the verb *protect*, used as an adjective, and it describes the result of *keeping*.

[Wikipedia object complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_complement)

> In grammar, an object complement is a predicative expression that follows a direct object of an attributive ditransitive verb or resultative verb and that complements the direct object of the sentence by describing it.[1](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-complex-transitive-verbs-1689888)[3] Object complements are constituents of the predicate. Noun phrases and adjective phrases most frequently function as object complements.[4]

The verb in the sentence *kept* is complex-transitive, in that it has a direct object *money* and the object complement *protected*. This link has multiple similar examples:

[Thoughtco complex-transitive](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-complex-transitive-verbs-1689888)

> In English grammar, a complex transitive is a verb that requires both a direct object and another object or an object complement.